# Am I improving my questions well?

Tags: support, questions

I've recently got a question ban, so I'm trying to improve my questions. Basically, I've already got good answers, so I am answering my own questions to show what I got. For example:

- [In C++, how is allocator-aware container assignment implemented? [EDIT]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801678/in-c-how-is-allocator-aware-container-assignment-implemented-edit)
- [How to copy a red-black tree, and what should its allocator be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218589/how-to-copy-a-red-black-tree-and-what-should-its-allocator-be)

Note that they also got explanations with source code. Is this a right way to improve my questions?

Also, I can't figure out how to improve these questions:

- [Does deallocation imply destruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248067/does-deallocation-imply-destruction)
  This question is too simple to find anything to be improved.
- [What is the locale name for Korean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672959/what-is-the-locale-name-for-korean)
  This question is now irrelevant for me, as I'm now using Ubuntu Yakkety and I can just use `ko_KR.utf8` for locale name.
- [Parameter pack expansion doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392779/parameter-pack-expansion-doesnt-work)
  Even though I edited this question, the rating still remains at -3.

Comment: Your first question *looks* like you've edited your question into an answer? If that is indeed what you're doing, then no - that is not the way to improve your questions.

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: Have a read of [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) article, and improve your questions where relevant. Your questions should *stay* questions, however. If you found a solution - post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: FWIW, I appreciate you taking the time to seek out feedback and try to improve. Some people will downvote you because this is meta but, I applaud your attitude :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, so far you are not making questions better/more aligned with SO recommendations.

Even more - you've edited answers into questions and potentially invalidated existing answers (i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40801678/revisions). Such edits should be rolled back.

If you are editing questions that asked more than one question - edit out all but one. Pay attention to keep existing answers (if any) to stay valid - you may have to reword your multiple questions into single one that is answered by others or keep only main one.

There are a lot of good resources - i.e. [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) by Jon Skeet is good article.

If you are trying to self-answer your questions - make sure to review guidance on Meta - looks through https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self-answer to see recommendations. Short version - question must be real question (with research, clear MCVE and like) and answers must actually answer question as asked.

Comment: Now question ban is lifted. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DannyuNDos How did you manage to lift your ban? Im on the same situation! And I have hoped a lot of people, I have had a lot of accepted answers and Im still banned.

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios This means either waiting out the ban or talking to a mod.

Comment: Thanks @CalebKleveter , didn't knew time could solve It. Im participating actively helping people hoping that could help as well. Where Can I Find Mod people?

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios On [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/). Something I might suggest is editing your questions. This could help to remove it. Also, don't go ask a mod to lift your ban. Ask why you got a ban and act on their suggestions. This [help post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) is for answers, but it might help you out.

Comment: "you've edited answers into questions and potentially invalidated existing answers" if the question was unfit, it's the answerers fault posting an answer instead of waiting until it's fit.

Comment: @CalebKleveter question bans aren't time based, so you just not "wait it out", but needs too actively work on getting out.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Probably should ave double checked that first. Thanks @Braiam for pointing that out!